# Using ArcGIS JavaScript to calculate length of line feature where clicked

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, linear-referencing

I am working with arcgis JavaScript API and a linear referencing feature.
I want to be able to click on a line of a feature and calculate the length from beginning of the line to where I clicked. Then add this length with a number from a field in the feature.

I cannot find a module similar for this in the API. Should I use vanilla JavaScript for this or has someone done this using the arcgis JavaScript library.

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript version 3 or 4?

Comment: I am using version 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a [click handler on your Feature Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#event-click). That will give you the Graphic that was clicked and the `mapPoint` (Point) of where the mouse was clicked in terms of location (x/y) on the map. Using those 2 pieces of data you would have to calculate the distance (looping through the "paths" of the polyline).